# interop.word, find and replace, erro:" O parâmetro da cadeia é muito longo."

Tags: c#, interoperabilidade

Estou usando um template para criar um documento, eu abro um documento que seria um template e uso find and replace para localizar e substituir palavras chaves que esta neste documento e logo depois salvo na minha área de trabalho como outro documento, tudo ocorre perfeitamente, mas quando eu vou tentar colocar um texto superior a 255 caracteres me deparo com este erro " O parâmetro da cadeia é muito longo." o que posso fazer? Sou um pouco leigo, se puderem postar um código que resolva meu problema eu agradeceria muito , obg desde já

```
private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {


        object missing = Type.Missing;

        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        object replaceText = true;



                wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                        ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                        ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                        ref nmatchAllForms, ref forward,
                        ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                        ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                        ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                        ref matchControl);



    }

    private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object savaAs)
    {
        List<int> processesbeforegen = getRunningProcesses();
        object missing = Missing.Value;

        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();

        Word.Document aDoc = null;

        if (File.Exists((string)filename))
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            object readOnly = false; 
            object isVisible = false;

            wordApp.Visible = false;


            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            aDoc.Activate();

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<n>", tbPlanoNmr.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<k>", tbPortaria.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<data>", tbData.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "PPPPP", tbNomeEtec.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<codigo>", tbCodigoEtec.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<municipio>", tbMunicipioEtec.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<eixo>", tbEixo.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<habilitacao>", tbHabilitacao.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<qualificacao>", tbQualificacao.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<serie>", tbModulo.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<componente>", tbMateria.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ch>", tbCHS.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<professor>", tbNomeProf.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<modulo>", Session["modulo"].ToString());

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<VI>", txtVI.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<VII>", txtVII.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<X>", txtX.InnerText);


            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                txtDidatico.Text += ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtProcedimento")).Text;
            }


            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<procedimento>", txtDidatico.Text);

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<instrumentos>", txtInstrumentos.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<criterios>", txtCriterios.InnerText);

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes1>", mes1.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes2>", mes2.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes3>", mes3.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes4>", mes4.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes5>", mes5.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<mes6>", mes6.InnerText);

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.1>", c11.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.2>", c12.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.3>", c13.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.4>", c14.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.5>", c15.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<1.6>", c16.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.1>", c21.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.2>", c22.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.3>", c23.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.4>", c24.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.5>", c25.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<2.6>", c26.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.1>", c31.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.2>", c32.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.3>", c33.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.4>", c34.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.5>", c35.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<3.6>", c36.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.1>", c41.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.2>", c42.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.3>", c43.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.4>", c44.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.5>", c45.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<4.6>", c46.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.1>", c51.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.2>", c52.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.3>", c53.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.4>", c54.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.5>", c55.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<5.6>", c56.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<atribuicoes>", taAtribuicoes.InnerText);

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<atividades>", taAtividades.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<competencia_extenso>", txtCompetenciaExtenso.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<evidencias>", txtEvidencia.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<habilidades>", txtHabilidade.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<competencia>", txtCompetencia.InnerText);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<base>", txtBase.InnerText);

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                txtHabilidadeP33.Text += ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtHabilidadeP3")).Text;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                txtBaseP33.Text += ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBaseP3")).Text;
            }

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<basenum>", txtHabilidadeP33.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<habilidadesnum>", txtBaseP33.Text);

            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "#", "^l");

            //this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$Date$$"     DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());




        }
        else
        {
            //Exibir mensagem: "a dose do arquivo não existe"

            return;
        }


        aDoc.SaveAs2(ref savaAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        List<int> processesaftergen = getRunningProcesses();
        killProcesses(processesbeforegen, processesaftergen);
    }


    public List<int> getRunningProcesses()
    {
        List<int> ProcessIDs = new List<int>();

        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id == clsProcess.Id)
                continue;
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("WINWORD"))
            {
                ProcessIDs.Add(clsProcess.Id);
            }
        }
        return ProcessIDs;
    }


    private void killProcesses(List<int> processesbeforegen, List<int> processesaftergen)
    {
        foreach (int pidafter in processesaftergen)
        {
            bool processfound = false;
            foreach (int pidbefore in processesbeforegen)
            {
                if (pidafter == pidbefore)
                {
                    processfound = true;
                }
            }

            if (processfound == false)
            {
                Process clsProcess = Process.GetProcessById(pidafter);
                clsProcess.Kill();
            }
        }
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tEnabled(bool state)
    {
        tbNomeProf.Enabled = state;

    }

    protected void btnGerarPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Template = "C:/Users/Bird/Desktop/temppp.doc";

        var NovoDocumento = "C:/Users/Bird/Desktop/PTD.doc";
        tEnabled(true);

        CreateWordDocument(Template, NovoDocumento);
        tEnabled(false);




    }
}
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/09c58208-d709-42ec-adab-4b933c62a002/replacementtext-o-parmetro-de-sequncia-de-caracteres-muito-longo-?forum=clientept

Comment: Obg, consegui resolver meu problema

Comment: Coloque sua resolução como resposta, assim poderá ajudar outra pessoar que buscar pelo mesmo problema =]

Answer (score 1):

eu estava usando find and replace desta forma

```
this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<texto>", texto.Text);
```

porem dava erro, pois a cadeia de caracteres era muito longa, então mudei para:

```
foreach (Word.Range tmpRange in aDoc.StoryRanges)
            {
                object findText = "<texto>";
                object replaceText = texto.Text;

                if (tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing))
                {
                    tmpRange.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Text = replaceText.ToString();
                }
            }
```